# Help with a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I need help with the graph of:

$x^2+y^2=|x|+|y|$

I tried squaring both sides and I got $x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-x^2-2xy+y^2=0$ but still can't figure the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real $x,|x|^2=x^2$

So, we have $$\left(|x|-\frac12\right)^2+\left(|y|-\frac12\right)^2=\frac12$$

Parametric form of $|x|$ will be $\dfrac12+\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\cos\theta$ which needs to be $\ge0\iff\cos\theta\ge-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: This leads to a nice and simple plot !